# How can i query children items in django

Tags: python, django

I have this

```
from django.db import models

class Kid(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Toy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Kid, related_name="kid_toys")
```

Now each kid has many toys.

I want to find those kids whose last toy bought has name which contains `new`

I'm trying like this

```
Kid.kids_toys.order_by('-created_date').first().filter(name__icontains='new')
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
kids = Kid.objects.filter(kid_toys=Toy.objects.filter(
    name__icontains='new').order_by('-created_date').first()
)
```

Comment: i could not get it fully . so does kid_toys will be all toys or it only works within toys of that kid

Comment: kid_toys is related_name which you defined in model. This expression should return all kids who own toy selected by sub query (name contain 'new', order by created_date desc with limit 1).

Comment: i don't know why but this is returning me only one kid always.

Comment: It happens, because you have foreign key from toy to kid. Toy can have only one owner. You should change foreign key to manytomany field.

Comment: but why i need to change that , because i want toy to have only one owner. one toy can't be owner by multiple kids.

Answer (score 0):

kids = Kid.objects.filter(kid__toys__in=Toy.objects.filter(
    name__icontains='new').order_by('-created_date').first()
)

Comment: this always gives me one result